# JavaScript find the index of a selected character in a textbox

Tags: javascript, select, indexing, char

I have a textbox with a 2-digit repeated number, (for example 11), and when I highlight the first digit, is there any functions that can return me an index of 0?
What I tried is that I have:

```
    var selectedString = window.getSelection();
    if (selectedString == textBoxValue.charAt(0)) {...}
```

This won't work because the selected string has the value "1" from the first digit of 11, so it will go into the if statement, but if I only selected the second digit, which selectedString will also be "1" and equals to textBoxValue.charAt(0), but I don't want that to happen because the second digit should correspond to textBoxValue.charAt(1).

So is there a way to get the index of the highlighted value, so I can do something like:

```
    if (selectedString == textBoxValue.charAt(0) && selectedString.index == 0) {...}
```

Comment: [Input Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) at MDN...

Answer (score 0):

```
var selection = window.getSelection ();
var offset = selection.anchorOffset;
```

So when we are selecting first digit, value of offset will be '0' & for second digit the value becomes '1'.

Comment: I tried that, but seems like textBoxValue.indexOf(selectedString) == 0  and textBoxValue.lastIndexOf(selectedString) == 1  are always true no matter what I selected.

Comment: I found a way to make it work finally, thanks for your help though!

Comment: welcome sammie....can you post your answer........it will help others in future..

Comment: sure, am i supposed to do that with edit or add comment on my post? im pretty new to this site...